# How do I use Colors in BlueprintJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blueprintjs

At the top of my react file I include the following:

```
import { Colors } from '@blueprintjs/core';
```

How do I go from this point on to using the [colors](http://blueprintjs.com/docs/#colors.core-colors) such as @blue3?

```
const homeStyle = {
 background: '@blue2';
};
```

This doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Colors exported as a single object, so to access it, you should do:

```
const homeStyle = {
   background: Colors.BLUE3;
};
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked. This simple example should be in the Colors docs.